# Chrome extension navigate and scrape several different sites

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

I want that my chrome extension would navigate to Gmail login page, run a  content script that logs in and then to navigate to another site (let's say drive.google.com) and then run another content script.

I want the user to monitor the process and that's why Selenium and PhantomJS are not suitable.

How can I identify that the login was successful?, I tried using MutationObserver but it doesn't work after redirects.

thanks

Comment: why Selenium is not suitable? If it's not a PhantomJS driver, it shows what is going on in browser and on screen and you can interrupt it

Comment: Google login always fails with selenium, Google detects suspicious log in attempt and therefore demands identifying information (phone number, another mail address, sms code..)

Comment: hm. I doubt it related to selenium itself, since it's generally the same browser. maybe it happens because you login too often or something like this? I seen implemented tests that included google signin with selenium

Comment: you can try something like Tampermonkey, maybe it would be better option